# Node modules issue: Only one default export allowed per module

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, npm-install, node-modules

This a issue we faced while doing an `npm install` on server which loaded new set of version for node_modules.

We have a module which looks like

```
export default class DemoComponent extend React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { ... }
)(DemoComponent);
```

It used to work fine before we  did `npm install` which loaded a new version of development dependencies.

ERROR LOG:

> Only one default export allowed per module.
>       at File.buildCodeFrameError (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:431:15)
>       at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:140:26)
>       at PluginPass.exit (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/lib/index.js:253:29)
>       at newFn (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:276:21)
>       at NodePath._call (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
>       at NodePath.call (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:117:8)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
>       at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
>       at TraversalContext.visit (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
>       at Function.traverse.node (/home/workspace/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:161:17)

Comment: You cannot have two `export default`, it doesn't make sense. One of them has to be the default, probably the latest one since it's the one connected to the store.

Answer (score 14):

You can not use more than one `export default` in a file. It doesn't make sense. If you need to export multiple things you need to use **named export**

**DemoComponent.js**

```
export class DemoComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { ... }
)(DemoComponent);
```

So the import statement would look like this:

```
import ConnectedComponent, {DemoComponent} from './DemoComponent';
```

When you use `export default` you can name your variable as you want but with **named export** you have to use the same variable name as the one that you export.

[More about export syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Btw you have a typo in your example. It's `extends`, not `extend`

Comment: Thanks, Dmitriy Nevzorov. I read about it http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html here.

Comment: What I don't get, why would that become an error after reinstalling `npm_monules`? Do you really have to `export default connect`? Why not `DemoComponent`?

Comment: because `connect` is a [react-redux HOC component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) that connects your `DemoComponent` to redux state. You want to export it to have a connected component otherwise your `DemoComponent` would not have access to the state